# Delphi Thread launched by another Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Hello all Stackoverflow readers and friends,

I have a thread, launched by a button click that queries an online API.

This API returns a url that a second thread downloads.

After some verifications, the first thread is launched like :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
     HTTPAPIThread : THTTPAPIThread;
begin
     //some verifications

     HTTPAPIThread.Create(API url + some parameter);
     HTTPAPIThread.OnAPI := APISource;
     HTTPAPIThread.OnTerminate := HTTPAPITerminated;
     HTTPAPIThread.Start;
end;
```

The APISource procedure does what is needed to extract the url from the json returned by the thread

The HTTPAPITerminated procedure handles the potential errors, and if none was encountered, launches the second thread like this :

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPAPITerminated(Sender: TObject);
var
     HTTPFULLThread : THTTPFULLThread;
begin
     if TThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
          begin
               //warns the user and gives details about the error
          end
     else //there was no error, launch the second thread
          begin
               HTTPFULLThread := THTTPFULLThread.Create(url from the API);
               HTTPFULLThread.OnFULL := FULLSource;
               HTTPFULLThread.OnTerminate := HTTPFULLTerminated;
               HTTPFULLThread.Start;    
          end;
end;
```

**QUESTION** : is it the correct place to trigger the second thread or should it be triggered at the end of the APISource which extracts the URL used by the second thread ?

This appeared logical to me to launch the second thread only if the first one succeeded but it might not be the correct way to implement things.

Thanks for reading my question.

Cheers

Mathias

Comment: Presumably `THTTPAPIThread` won't fire its `OnAPI` event if an error occurs. I would probably launch the next thread from `OnAPI`, and use `OnTerminated` only for error reporting and cleanup. Then `OnAPI` doesn't need to save the URL for `OnTerminated` to use. A cleaner solution would be to give `THTTPAPIThread` a property to hold the extracted URL, get rid of `OnAPI` altogether, and do everything in `OnTerminated` only. You can typecast the `Sender` to `THTTPAPIThread` to access the new property.  Similar considerations apply to `THTTPFULLThread` as well.

Comment: I would implement all tasks inside single thread to exclude potential problems. But your solution seems ok except some nuance: in `HTTPFULLTerminated` method if you have ti update GUI, use `TThread.Synchronize` "magic" call savely call functions in MainThread